# My js file is not loaded in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, requirejs

My steps:

1) Load my file `slider.js` to: `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/default/web/js`.

2) Create `requirejs-config.js` to: `app/design/frontend/Vendorname/default`

```
var config = {
        paths: {
            slider:        "js/slider"
        },
        shim: {
            slider: {
                deps: ["jquery"]
            }
        }
    };
```

3) `rm -R pub/static/*`

4) `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

When I open site, `slider.js` is not loaded.
**I need to call him, that he began to load?**
I read a lot of [Magento 2: Javascript Init Scripts](http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts/), [Use custom JavaScript](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html).

Realy need help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Way you are including **custom js in requirejs-config-js is correct** , but you must need to **load this js in your template(.phtml) file**.

**Add below code in your .phtml template file :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    require(['jquery', 'slider'],function($){
        (function() {
             //code goes here
        })(jQuery);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If I write this in site-admin-panel/home-page/content. Will it work?

Comment: Yes it will work . You can call your slider block in homepage as well

Answer (score 3):

Magento 2 uses RequireJs to load the js. So, our custom script will not load until we call it via RequireJS. For example, in your phtml, we can call

```
        <script>
            require([
                "jquery",
                "slider"
            ], function($, slider){

               ......

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: If I write this in site-admin-panel/home-page/content. Will it work?

Comment: Yes, may will work.