# Magento 2 - Load js in adminhtml area by require-js

Tags: magento2, javascript, adminhtml

I'm trying to load a js file in adminhtml area.

I've created my module and **requirejs-config.js** file under **app/code/vendorName/moduleName/view/adminhtml/web** folder:

```
var config = {

        map: {
            "*": {
                stickerConfig: 'vendorName_moduleName/js/stickerConfig'
            }
        }
    };
```

I see this piece of code in **pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js** file.

Then I created my **stickerConfig.js** in **app/code/Mainf/Stickers/view/adminhtml/web/js**

When I load backend pages, I don't find my javascript in list of js downloaded by browser.

What's wrong?

Comment: Read more [My js file is not loaded in Magento 2](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/my-js-file-is-not-loaded-in-magento-2)

Comment: You need to call your custom script in your phtml template.

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh I've already used this method (load js by requirejs) in frontend area and it works fine. This should be the right way to improve page loading performance. I am not able to load js by requirejs in adminhtml area but I find documentation about it.

Are you sure of what you're writing?

Comment: Make sure your template is called in adminhtml area?

Comment: The page URL is **domain.ext/admin/admin/system_config/edit/section/my_section/** so its template should be in adminhtml area.


The idea is, after creating a radiobox field for extension configuration in **system.xml** (I've already done), to enable/disable another configuration field based on radiobox choise so I think I need to do that by javascript.


Is this the right way?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh: thanks to you advice I've found a solution: I load my js code in an adminhtml template called by **adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml** layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved in this way..

**app/code/vendorName/moduleName/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml**:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="vendorName\moduleName\Block\Config" template="vendorName_moduleName::js.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/vendorName/moduleName/view/adminhtml/templates/js.phtml**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(
        ['jquery'],
        function($) {
            $(function() {
                // My js code
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah! Good job!

Answer (score 1):

Load js file using the requirejs-config.js

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

requirejs-config.js

```
   var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            loadcatalogs:'BA_BStore/js/loadcatalogs'
        }
    }
};
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/web/js/loadcatalogs.js

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    "use strict";
    return function(config) {
        $("#division_id").on('change', function() {
            var divisionId = $("#b_division_id").val();
            $.ajax({
            url: config.ajaxUrlValue,
            type: "POST",
            data: { divisionId:divisionId },
            showLoader: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response);            
            }
        });      
    });
}
});
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/templates/loadjs.phtml

```
<?php
    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
    $ajaxUrl = $viewModel->getAjaxUrl();
?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
{
    "*": {
        "loadcatalogs": {
            "ajaxUrlValue": "<?= __($ajaxUrl)?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

app/code/BA/BStore/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_system_config_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer">
            <container name="basys_load_js" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="basys_load_js">
                <block name="basysloadjs.viewmodel" template="BA_BStore::loadjs.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="view_model" xsi:type="object">BA\BStore\ViewModel\LoadajaxUrl</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```